# join confusion for mssql

Tags: sql-server, join

So I want to get some data from table-A if some attributes are available for the items. I'm using the following criteria to filter out the records

```
select * from product p
inner join AttributeCodesByProduct atp
on atp.product_id = p.product_id 
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(atp.attrVal)) LIKE 'Sil - ghi' 
OR LTRIM(RTRIM(atp.attrVal)) LIKE 'Sil - def'
OR LTRIM(RTRIM(atp.attrVal)) LIKE 'Sil - abc'
OR LTRIM(RTRIM(atp.attrVal)) not like 'xyz'

where p.class = 2
```

Basically I want to retrieve all products with Class 2 and check the attribute table to make sure they have attributes such as ('Sil - ghi', 'Sil - def', 'Sil - abc') and don't have an attribute like 'xyz'. I'm not sure if it should be a right join or inner join but I don't want any extra items from attribute. For a single product, there may be many different attributes.

Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to write your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   product p 
       INNER JOIN attributecodesbyproduct atp 
               ON atp.product_id = p.product_id 
                  AND Ltrim(Rtrim(atp.attrval)) IN ( 'Sil - ghi','Sil - def', 'Sil - abc' ) 
WHERE  p.class = 2
```

Or If you don't want to include a `product` when it has atleast one `'xyz'` as attribute then try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM   product p 
       INNER JOIN attributecodesbyproduct atp 
               ON atp.product_id = p.product_id 
WHERE  p.class = 2 
       AND Ltrim(Rtrim(atp.attrval)) IN ('Sil - ghi', 'Sil - def', 'Sil - abc') 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   product p1 
                          INNER JOIN attributecodesbyproduct atp1 
                                  ON atp1.product_id = p1.product_id 
                   WHERE  p.product_id = p1.product_id 
                   GROUP  BY p1.product_id 
                   HAVING Count(CASE WHEN Ltrim(Rtrim(atp.attrval)) = 'xyz' THEN 1 END) = 0)
```

Comment: Understood but I have this other clause there as well     "LTRIM(RTRIM(atp.attrVal)) not like 'xyz'". And is inner join the right type of join in this case?